# django-rest-framework raise AuthencationFailed cause 500 response

Tags: django-rest-framework

I add an Authencation to default authencations in django-rest-framekwork, and raise AuthenticationFailed when error occurs as documented in api-guide. It returns a 500 reponse, saying an exception of AuthenticationFailed was thrown out, while it should return a 401 or 403 response according to the [document](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#custom-authentication).

I check the source. It catch this exception and re-raise in Request._authenticate(), and never catch again.

Am i missing something?

I'm using Django 1.7 and django-rest-framework 3.3.3 .

The code is as simple as you can imagine:

```
class CustomAuthentication(authentication.BaseAuthentication):
     def authenticate(self, request):
         raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed
```

and in settings:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'path.to.CustomAuthentication',
    ],
}
```

Comment: Please provide some code which gives some hint as to how are you authenticating and what could have possibly gone wrong.

Comment: it's nothing about how I am authenticating. I only want a 401 or 403 response instead of a 500 response.

Comment: Thank you for updating the question, can you please also share the view in which you are authenticating?

Comment: I use a standard ModelViewSet.

Comment: thanks Muhammad! I found my the method initialize_request in my view is overwritten globally. I will update this question after I solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def initialize_request(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    request = super(TheViewSet, self).initialize_request(
        request, *args, **kwargs)
    return request
```

replaced with:

```
def initialize_request(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    _request = super(TheViewSet, self).initialize_request(
        request, *args, **kwargs)
    return _request
```

Sorry for delay. I got a holiday and had a trip these days. I still don't know how it gets problems.

Comment: Looks like the problem has been solved for good, happy for you  :-)